# fluent-ffmpeg no way to speed up GIF

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, fluent-ffmpeg

With the node.js package `fluent-ffmpeg`, there seems to be no way to speed up the video/gif I'm taking. I know you can use setpts with regular ffmpeg but whenever I try to incorporate that command into the programmatic usage of fluent-ffmpeg by saying something like: `.outputOption("-vf", "setpts=0.5*PTS")` the program throws an error saying I'm using the command incorrectly. Am I incorporating it wrong or is there no way to use this command in fluent-ffmpeg?

This is what I currently have for the file conversion from h264 to gif. The output options written below are working as they should:

```js
var inFilename = "/home/pi/Videos/video.h264";
var outFilename = "/home/pi/Videos/video.gif";
ffmpeg(inFilename)
  .outputOption("-vf", "scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,fps=75")
  .save(outFilename)
  .run()
```